# animate text alignment for UILabel in swift

Tags: swift, animation, uilabel, text-alignment

So my question is more of a challenge in the end. Maybe Im going into a wrong direction so I though maybe I could ask for ideas.

**the context:**

I have a set of string (place names) and I want to suggest answers based on user inputs in a UITextView.

**The method:**

I Used a combination of two UILabels and one UITextView to achieve a working results: The suggestionLabel is in the background, the searchLabel in the middle, and a searchInput text view on the foreground. The textview enables interaction but text's alpha is set to 0 (I didn't want to consume time with padding and insets relative to the various screen size and autolayout constraints I have). When typing, the changes are reflected on the searchLabel, and the suggestion based on inputs on the suggestionLabel.

**The goal:**

It's a visual goal. when the user select a place based on suggestion, the place's profile fades in and its title is set at the exact same place than was the search text. (all of this to serve a good looking transition).

**The challenge:**

The search input, label and place's profile title have to be centered (Im speaking about text alignment here). To make this work with the different layer of text, I used a set of auto layout constraints where blocks are centered in the views, with dynamic width, and an original text alignment set to .Left

Having the alignment set to .Center breaks the text layers perfect overlap.
So, I though about keeping it this way and make the transition from .Left alignement to .Center when users validate their choices.

My problem is that textAlignment doesn't seems to be something that we can smoothly animate. So I was wondering if there was a trick of some sort I could use :)

thanks you for any idea you could come up with.

Im not sure it's relevant but here is the code wrote:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { //Handle the text changes here

        displaySearch.text = textView.text
        displaySearch.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        displaySearch.font = UIFont(name: searchView.font.fontName, size: 23)

        if suggestView.text!.rangeOfString(searchView.text) != nil{
            println("exists")
        }
        else{
            suggestView.text = ""
        }

        //USER INPUT
        let scope = self.searchView.text

        //SCANNING SUGGESTION DICT
        for(var i = 0; i < dict.count; i++){
            let stringon = dict[i]["place"] as! String
            println(stringon)

            if let range = stringon.rangeOfString(scope.lowercaseString) {
                if range.startIndex == stringon.startIndex {
                    suggestView.text = stringon.capitalizedString
                    searchView.text = searchView.text.capitalizedString
                    suggestView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
                    suggestView.font = UIFont(name: searchView.font.fontName, size: 23)
                    suggestView.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
                }
            }
        }
    }


func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if(text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            //ANIMATE TEXT ALIGNMENT
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```